# How to create a list with most if not all Python3 Error Messages

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, readability

Some error messages (those encountered by the beginners mostly) are not friendly enough for beginners themselves:
Error: 'str ' object does not support item assignment

I think a more suggestive, less cryptic message would be:
Error: value reassignment inside the 'str' object not supported

Also, to create in Python a list of all tags stackoverflow supports might come handy as for me it will take a lifetime to get 1500 reputation and create a new tag. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46098957/edit) your question and add tag [tag:python3].

Comment: There would be many error messages, how would you find out all of those ?